# Rotina de backup dos arquivos de desenvolvimento

Tags: git, backup, cloud

seguinte: eu trabalho em um escritório de design e sou o responsável pela área de desenvolvimento. O escritório tem um servidor central onde ficam hospedados todos os arquivos de trabalho.

Porém, para trabalhar com desenvolvimento, não podemos trabalhar diretamente no servidor pela política de segurança da empresa (uso de FTP etc) e outras questões relativas à performance e pela utilização de node_modules, que não precisam ser backupeados.

Já tentamos usar One Drive e Drop Box, sem conseguir bons resultados. Atualmente, apelamos para programa de backup (Cobian) mas não é a melhor solução.

O ideal seria algum serviço de backup na nuvem em que pudéssemos criar um recurso semelhante ao .git_ignore, para que pudéssemos restringir os arquivos a serem backupeados.

Caso houvesse algum tipo de automação diária do Git (que desconheço) isso também ajudaria.

Comment: e porque nao usao gitlab? https://about.gitlab.com/pricing/#self-managed

Comment: você também pode criar uma rotina de backup com o [cron](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/scheduling-tasks-with-cron-jobs--net-8800) pra fazer o backup só dos arquivos que não estiverem no seu ".gitignore". nesse caso vai ser necessário entender um pouco de shell script.

Answer (score 0):

Em se tratando de arquivos de código, e relacionados, por exemplo: imagens que estão na aplicação, arquivo de áudio, etc...; a melhor prática é que tudo isso esteja versionado em um [controlador de versão](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sistema_de_controle_de_vers%C3%B5es).

Atualmente, talvez, o mais utilizado seja o [Git](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Git), porém você ainda encontrará [Mercurial](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mercurial), ainda dentro dos DVCS, e ainda o [SVN](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subversion), [TFVC](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/tfvc/index?view=azure-devops), dentro dos CVCS.

> Para saber a diferença entre CVCS e DVCS veja estes links:
>   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/111031/comparison-between-centralized-and-distributed-version-control-systems
>   https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Version_control#Distributed_revision_control

Alguns destes citados são produtos, por exemplo o TFVC, já outros possuem implementações, por exemplo para o SVN existem diversos plug-ins client para acesso.

O mais recomendado atualmente é o Git, popularidade conquistada pelo Github.com, tanto que a Microsoft até mesmo implementou no [Azure DevOps](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/?view=azure-devops), na vertical hoje chamada de [Azure Repos](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/?view=azure-devops), em um novo projeto é possível escolher entre Git e TFVC, e a recomendação da própria Microsoft é pelo Git.

Portanto, o ideal é que você escolha um desses versionadores e utilize-os. Se você escolher a versão on-premise, deverá fazer o backu-up, por exemplo, o Azure DevOps Server tem a opção de fazer o back-up. Já o Azure DevOps Services, que é um serviço na nuvem, não é necessário! Assim como o Github.com.

O interessante de usar Git é que você poderá trocar de serviço, sem ter perda alguma, você pode testar o Github.com ou o Azure DevOps e no futuro migrar para qualquer outro serviço de storage de Git, pois todos serão compatíveis.

Uma má prática é usar os serviços que você citou, One Drive ou Dropbox, pois não são próprios para versionamento de código.